# Evaluating the integral $\int (x^2-1)^{\frac{-3}{2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve the differential equation:
$$\displaystyle f'(x) = (x^2-1)^{-\frac{3}{2}}, f(2)=\frac{3-2\sqrt 3}{3}$$

Which basically amounts to solving the integral $\int (x^2-1)^{-\frac{3}{2}} \mathrm{d} x$. I was thinkng of using $\int (x^2-1)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \mathrm{d} x = \operatorname{arcosh} x$ but I can't haven't managed to simplify it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may write
$$
x=\cosh u, \quad dx=\sinh u\: du,
$$ giving
$$
\int\frac1{(x^2-1)^{3/2}}dx=\int\frac1{\sinh^2 u}du=-\text{cotanh}(u)+C= -\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}+C
$$

Comment: Too fast for this slow guy!  +1

Comment: I can't believe I missed that, and I did that substitution a couple of times too. Thanks!

Comment: @Dr.MV Thank you! (but you are far from bing slow:)

Comment: @Gonate Then you can find the value of $C$. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I thought it might be instructive to present an approach that uses integration by parts, rather than hyperbolic trigonometric substitution.  To that end, we begin by writing

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{(x^2-1)^{3/2}}&=\frac{(1-x^2)+x^2}{(x^2-1)^{3/2}}\\\\
&=\frac{x^2}{(x^2-1)^{3/2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}
\end{align} \tag 1$$

Using $(1)$ permits our writing

$$\int \frac{1}{(x^2-1)^{3/2}}\,dx=\int \frac{x^2}{(x^2-1)^{3/2}}\,dx-\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}} \,dx \tag 2 $$

Integrating by parts the first integral on the right-hand side of $(2)$ yields

$$\int \frac{x^2}{(x^2-1)^{3/2}}\,dx=-x\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}+\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\,dx +C \tag 3$$

Finally, using $(3)$ in $(2)$ reveals

$$\int \frac{1}{(x^2-1)^{3/2}}\,dx=-x\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}+C$$

which agrees with the result reported by @OlivierOloa from using hyperbolic trigonometric substitution!

Comment: Thanks! I found this pretty useful, especially if one of these come up when I won't be able to look up standard results.

Comment: You're quite welcome.  My pleasure.  It's always better to have more tools at one's disposal as there is more than one way to "skin an integral."